# Homogeneous Solution of a 4th Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a a 4th order ODE and I used Separation of Variables method and after that I have an equation as follows.

[image: Equation]

$n, l_1, l_2$ are constant and the equation is in terms of $r$.

Now I don't know how to solve this , In other words I want the Homogeneous Solution.

Comment: What was the original problem?

Comment: It is originally the bi-Helmholtz equation. After that I used the Separation of Variables method, it's changed to above equation.
This is the original equation: https://i.imgur.com/GRcl0WU.jpg